# Refresh Select Option

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select

I am summing up some values of selectors with this code:

```js
$('.menge_calc').change(function(){
    var sum = 0;
    $('select :selected').each(function() {
        sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
     $("#sum").html(sum);
  
  rest = 10-sum;
  
 $("select option").each(function(){
     if($(this).val()>rest){ 
      $(this).hide(); 
     }
     
     if($(this).val()<=rest){ 
      $(this).show(); 
     }   
    
    }); 
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="menge_calc" name="menge_1" id="menge_1">
<option class="option_calc option_0" value="0">0</option>
<option class="option_calc option_1" value="1">1</option>
<option class="option_calc option_2" value="2">2</option>
<option class="option_calc option_3" value="3">3</option>
<option class="option_calc option_4" value="4">4</option>
<option class="option_calc option_5" value="5">5</option>
<option class="option_calc option_6" value="6">6</option>
<option class="option_calc option_7" value="7">7</option>
<option class="option_calc option_8" value="8">8</option>
<option class="option_calc option_9" value="9">9</option>
<option class="option_calc option_10" value="10">10</option>
</select>

<select class="menge_calc" name="menge_2" id="menge_2">
<option class="option_calc option_0" value="0">0</option>
<option class="option_calc option_1" value="1">1</option>
<option class="option_calc option_2" value="2">2</option>
<option class="option_calc option_3" value="3">3</option>
<option class="option_calc option_4" value="4">4</option>
<option class="option_calc option_5" value="5">5</option>
<option class="option_calc option_6" value="6">6</option>
<option class="option_calc option_7" value="7">7</option>
<option class="option_calc option_8" value="8">8</option>
<option class="option_calc option_9" value="9">9</option>
<option class="option_calc option_10" value="10">10</option>
</select>

<select class="menge_calc" name="menge_3" id="menge_3">
<option class="option_calc option_0" value="0">0</option>
<option class="option_calc option_1" value="1">1</option>
<option class="option_calc option_2" value="2">2</option>
<option class="option_calc option_3" value="3">3</option>
<option class="option_calc option_4" value="4">4</option>
<option class="option_calc option_5" value="5">5</option>
<option class="option_calc option_6" value="6">6</option>
<option class="option_calc option_7" value="7">7</option>
<option class="option_calc option_8" value="8">8</option>
<option class="option_calc option_9" value="9">9</option>
<option class="option_calc option_10" value="10">10</option>
</select>

<div id="sum">SUM OF SELECTED OPTIONS</div>
```

Sum of all fields should max be 10 and people should only be allowed to chose possible options. It works quite fine, but editing doesn't work correctly.

Let's say the options 3, 1 and 4 are firstly chosed. Now User wants to change and clicks on the last select (where 4 was chosed). He should now be able to chose between 10-3-1=6 => So 6,5,4,3,2,1,0 should be possible. But my code only alows 10-3-1-4=2 0> So 2,1,0.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you aren't including the value that is already selected.

e.g. If 2 is selected, and you are at "8". Then the max that that selectbox can select is actually 4 (Because the existing 2 is being included already).

Here's the javascript to make it work :

```
$('.menge_calc').change(function(){
var sum = 0;
$('select :selected').each(function() {
    sum += Number($(this).val());
});
$("#sum").html(sum);

rest = 10-sum;

$("select").each(function()
{
var currentValue = Number($(this).val());
var maxValue = currentValue + rest;
$(this).children("option").each(function(){
    if($(this).val()>maxValue){ 
        $(this).hide(); 
    }

    if($(this).val()<=maxValue){ 
        $(this).show(); 
    }           

    }); 
 });
```

});

And here's a JSFiddle with it working : https://jsfiddle.net/mu8cnu6j/